# best way to parse files (non language specific)

Tags: regex, parsing

This isn't really centred around a language but could be if you want to use that language as an example.

My question is this, I have a large file I want to parse looking for specific headers (reading it in in hex), say for example I'm looking for F133 AFFC 4000 5200 F1FC, what's the best way to look for this without reading in one byte at a time, checking if it meets F1 then the next byte to see if it meets 33 and so on (basically nested IF statements is how I'm currently doing it)? I'm using nested IF statements as I can't read in say X bytes at a time because that could cut of half of what I'm looking for and I would miss it.

Once you have found this how would you then say read in 4 bytes 40 bytes in after the header, then say 8 bytes 120 bytes in after the header if this makes sense?

I'm just looking to write my code efficiently and after some googling there aren't that many clear answers for me? Is the answer as simple as just using RegEx?

Comment: Do you need to be super efficient, or are you aiming for readable code?

Comment: I guess readable code, as the file shouldn't get that big, I just like to learn best practices.

Comment: Is the input file well structured and unchanging (as far as structure goes?) What created the file?

Comment: FYI Parsing <> Searching

Comment: No it appears to move around, it's a Microsoft database file which is some proprietary format (naturally). So I can't use offsets from the start I have to look for entry signatures.

Comment: @rheitzman yeah sorry I sort of used the interchangeable in this instance.

Comment: The solution to this would be a one-liner in many languages, and several lines fo code in others. Pick a language, as file I/O is a matter of a (most probably standard) library.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski can we say c# for example?

Comment: Reading the first block (say 1024 bytes) into  a buffer and then parsing that seems a lot faster (because blocks *are* faster) and easier (because you can backtrack etc).

Comment: @tripleee I can't do that as I might end up reading up to half way through the file signature and miss it.